# Python Panda Graph change value in top right

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe I plot using:

```
scoreDF.plot(title="Scores")
plt.xlabel("Number of Games")
plt.ylabel("Scores")
plt.show()
```

When it's plotted, there is a value in the top right that show's 0.
How do I set this? I would like to have it show the highest value in the graph.
Thanks in advance!

Image attached of graph:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the answers above, I used this and it gave me the max value in the top right.

```
plt.legend(scoreDF.max())
```

Thanks everyone for their help!

Answer (score 0):

You should give labels to the columns, it shows the column labels. You could set it by:

```py
scoreDF.columns = ['Column label']
```

In order to show the max value:

```py
scoreDF.columns = ['Max value: {}'.format(scoreDF.max())]
```

Comment: I tried to do the Max value you recommended here, but it simply didn't do anything. The value is still 0.